# Deleting Multiple Files

Tags: windows, command-line

I am deleting multiple files with the command:

```
del /s *.doc *.rtf *.txt
```

I get the error Could Not Find *.doc.

How can I get the command to continue deleting RTF and TXT files when there are no more DOC files?

I want to use a single command so I can traverse the subdirectories once, instead of executing a delete command for each file type individually.

Comment: Do you have to have it on one line of code?  If yes, I'm a C# dev, so I'd write a quick app to do it (overkill yes!).  Maybe powershell can help?

Answer (score 5):

It just says so because it couldn't find any `.doc` files; it still deletes all other files matching the arguments.

If you just don't like the message, then redirect it away:

```
del /s *.doc *.rtf *.txt 2>nul
```

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une pipe!